# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match

Tags: ssl, certificate, tomcat

This is about how to import a SSL Certificate provided vendor to Tomcat Web Server.

Note: The CSR generated on Network balancer and the certificate is generated based on the provided CSR.

Can someone help me with the steps to how to import the certificate (.cer) to the tomcat server.

as i said the csr is generated on loadbalancer , I think it is conflicting. How to make the cert work and Import on tomcat?

Comment: You may want to add some extra info, such as tomcat server version, more details on the given error, etc.

Have you tried to use certbot to automatically create a new cert and import it to Tomcat, then LOOK HOW DID IT IMPORT IT and change the one created by certbot to the one provided by your load balancer? May look stupid, but who knows. Here you are some instructions provided by a cetificate provider. It should be the same for you: https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/tomcat-keytool.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly, using keytool utility have exported the private key

   ```
   keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore keystorefile.jks -srcalias alias -destkeystore exportedfilefile.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12

   openssl pkcs12 -in exportedfilefile.p12 -nocerts -nodes
   ```
2. Secondly using open ssl , exported the .pfx file using the privatekey and .cert (servercertificate).

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out exportedfilename.pfx -inkey  privatekey -in servercertificate.crt
   ```